# Убрать несколько символов в конце значения href

Tags: php, href

Есть ссылка следующего вида, в которой урл подтягивается из бд:

```
<a href="/{{$page['slug']}}">
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы у этого урла в конце убиралось 5 знаков? Без редактирования самого урла в бд само собой.

Спасибо!

Comment: `substr($string, 0, -5);` [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php)

Comment: а как это использовать? я не сильно шарю) спасибо!

Comment: `substr($page['slug'], 0, -5);`

Comment: Шикарно! Спасибо тебе, добрый человек;)